# TextField in sheet that accepts focus immediately without any noticeable delay

Tags: swiftui, focus, textfield, overlay

I want to open a `Sheet` in SwiftUI that 1) contains a `TextField` which 2) accepts focus *immediately*. Unfortunately, as demonstrated in the attached clip, there’s a short but noticeable delay before the keyboard pops up. This makes the transition into the focused state not as smooth as I would like (UI shifting to make room for the keyboard).

[image]

Minimum reproducible example:

```
struct TestRootView: View {
    
    @State private var sheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Open sheet") {
            sheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @FocusState var isFocused
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("title", text: $text)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onAppear {
                isFocused = true
            }
        
        Button("Close") {
            dismiss()
        }.font(.title)
        .padding()
        .background(.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried a couple of workarounds, but no luck ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat as you in not liking the delay on showing the keyboard. Note that I haven't done a ton of testing, but using the `Introspect` library along with `becomesFirstResponder` seems to work pretty well.

Using your sample code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

struct TestRootView: View {
    @State private var sheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Open sheet") {
            sheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @FocusState var isFocused
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("title", text: $text)
          .introspectTextField { textField in
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
          }
          .focused($isFocused)
        
        Button("Close") {
            dismiss()
        }
        .font(.title)
        .padding()
        .background(.black)
    }
}
```